# Searching a record by name and id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working with ASP.Net MVC with SQL server management studio.
Now how would I get a record by a given name and/or id?

Currently, I only find a record using the id which just works fine, but when searching a record by name, it won't find the correct record.

My current code looks something like this:

```
//Student.cs

public partial class Student
{
    public int No { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> mobileno { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

```
//Index.cshtml

@using (Html.BeginForm("search", "CrudManually", FormMethod.Post))
{
     @Html.TextBox("id")<br/>
     @Html.TextBox("searchString")<br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
}
```

```
//CrudManuallyController.cs

public class CrudManuallyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View(db.manages.ToList());
        //return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult search(int id,string searchString,Student students)
    {

            var query = db.students.Where(d => d.No == id).AsQueryable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            { 
                query = query.Where(d => d.Name.Contains(searchs)); // generate an error local variable 'searchs' before it is declared.
            }

            var  searchs = query.ToList();
            return View("index",searchs);


    }
}
```

Now how would I query for an id and a name at the same time?

Comment: l2sql does support int, and l2e does as well. So where are the issues? What is the desired result?

Comment: added an answer

Comment: @jarakbans i hope my answer has helped

Comment: @Gabriel Llorico did not run it will be given an error

Comment: @jarakbans what error did it give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your controller

```
public class CrudManuallyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View(db.manages.ToList());
        //return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult search(int? id, string searchString,Student students)
    {
        //Lambda Linq to entity does not support Int32
        //var search = (from d in db.students where d.No == Convert.ToInt32(id) && d.Name == id select d).ToList();
        //var search = db.students.Where(d => d.No == Convert.ToInt32(id) && d.Name == id).ToList();
        query = db.students.AsQueryable();
        if (id.HasValue)
        {
            var studentId = id.Value;
            query = query.Where(d => d.No == studentId);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            query = query.Where(d => d.Name.Contains(searchString));

        var search = query.ToList();
        return View("index",search);
    }
}
```

update your .cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("search", "CrudManually", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBox("id")
    @Html.TextBox("searchString")
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
}
```

Comment: this line generates an error ```query = query.Where(d => d.Name.Contains(searchs));``` see i update my code

Comment: @jarakbans sorry, shoud be `.Name.Contains(searchString)`. Also updated my code

Comment: Lloricor : The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult searchhttps://stackoverflow.com/users/2122217/gabriel-llorico why you use two textbox can u suggest onlyone textbox for id and name??

Comment: @jarakbans ohh, okay, so it can be and/or, got it

Comment: @jarakbans you want one textbox to cater for both `Name` search and `ID` search? is that what you really want? to cater to a search for int and string? what if the search is `1 Jarak`? how should the search works?

Comment: exactly int? it accepts the null value and int cannot accept null value ok thanks can u help more because I have two search box individually id and name can u give suggestion for one textbox and user search id then find a record id and when user search name then finds a record name??

Comment: @jarakbans question, what if the user inputs `1 Jarak`, how will the search work?

Comment: when user enter ```1``` then 1 record data found when user enter ```jarak``` then found jarak record found either id or name both are work in one search box?

Comment: what i mean is what if he enters both, `1 jarak` as a `searchString`. How will we handle it? search it as `.name.Contains("1 jarak");`?

Comment: means user either enter ```1``` or ```jarak``` then found the record as a searchString

Comment: no what i mean is, for example, the user enters `1 jarak` not `1` or `jarak` but the `string = "1 jarak"`

Comment: ```string = "1 jarak" ``` that is wrong. I mean string=1 or string=jarak

Answer (score 0):

You can get 2 way

```
list.Where(i => i.Property == value).FirstOrDefault();       // C# 3.0+

list.Find(i => i.Property == value);                         // C# 3.0+
```

if you find any item, you can get that. If you dont find an item, you get null.

Tell me if you resolve :)

Comment: list how to implement list I don't idea using a list I can find record name and id?

Comment: your list is your Queryable() ! :) query (var query) contains all your student. You can check inside that